# How to set multiple variables at once in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have been setting multiple variables like this

```
function doSomething() {

    var FirstName = $FirstName.data("ov");
    var LastName = $LastName.data("ov");
    var Company = $Company.data("ov");
    var Website = $Website.data("ov");

}
```

I just read some reviewed code and both reviewers advised setting the variables in a single statement, like this:

```
function doSomething() {

    var FirstName = $FirstName.data("ov"),
        LastName = $LastName.data("ov"),
        Company = $Company.data("ov"),
        Website = $Website.data("ov");

}
```

What would be the advantage of doing it the second way? Is there a performance benefit? Is it that there is less code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a very good book called [JavaScript Patterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596806752):

> Using a single **var** statement at the top of your functions is a useful pattern to adopt.  It has the following benefits:
>
> - Provides a single place to look for all the local variables needed by the function
> - Prevents logical errors when a variable is used before it's defined
> - Helps you remember to declare variables and therefore minimize globals
> - Is less code (to type and to transfer over the wire)

The author also recommends initializing the variables when you declare them when possible.

Comment: Those are some compelling reasons, the least of which is a performance boost.

Comment: @Evik - mucking up the global namespace, by forgetting the var keyword can have huge performance impacts.  So, I assume you are referring to the "is less code" bullet.

Comment: I tend to not mistakes like that, forgetting to var it.  I made that mistake early on and killed my browser memory doing a bunch of Ajax stuff. Assuming I code it correctly, it will have little performance advantage. The real advantage will be in creating the necessary local variables right away at the top of the function.

Comment: I'd argue that at least #1 and #3 do not matter in this case. The first code example does provide a "single place to look for" and minimizes globals just as much as the second example. In fact, the only example of those 4 that seems to make a difference in this case is #4 and, even then, not by much(in this particular case - assuming spaces are used - there are exactly as many bytes being sent)

Answer (score 1):

There should be no noticeable difference in performance (even if there was, it would most likely be negligible) and they mean the same.

It's just a matter of picking the one that's most readable. Frankly, I don't find the second example more readable than the first, but this is subjective.

EDIT: One possible difference is that smaller code (assuming those are charaters replacing "var" are tabs and not spaces) might reduce traffic, making the page faster. However, in practice, I think the best JS minifiers should handle that sort of thing for you.

Comment: I think you meant "there should be NO noticeable..." Is that correct?

Comment: @EvikJames Indeed. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, [there is little difference](http://jsperf.com/single-var-vs-multiple-var) across both methods. [Another test found here](http://jsperf.com/var-type-comparison) which has greater browser coverage.

In terms of readability, I'd go for the multiple variables using a single `var` since it is less messy.

All in all, it depends on you.